# Var.$logged defined in global.php, not picked up by index.php

Tags: php, mysql

I was attempting to follow along with the tutorial at the YouTube channel [Helping Develop](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=__qEvukd5og)

when I came across a few issues.  The first being his logout code in tutorial #5 doesn't work anymore due to the changed

```
if(session_is_registered()
```

I think I have replaced that properly with

```
if( isset($_SESSION[$username])){
```

But now I am getting an error that says

> "Notice: Undefined variable: logged in C:\xampp\htdocs\membership\index.php on line 2"

When I check line 2 of index it shows that i am including global.php first

```
    <?php include_once('scripts/global.php');
     if($logged==1){
    header("Location:home.php");
        exit();
    }
    ?>
```

So then I check global.php which has $logged=1 so it should be defined...unless I am missing something.  I am really trying to learn more here, so any help would be appreciated in explaining what is wrong, and why....  Thank you.

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    include_once('scripts/connect.php');

     //checking if the sessions are set
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
               $session_username=$_SESSION['username'];
               $session_pass=$_SESSION['pass'];
               $session_id=$_SESSION['id'];
               
               //checking the member data
               $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE
     id='id' AND password='pass' LIMIT 1")or die("Could not check member");
               $count_count=mysql_num_rows($query);
               if(count_count>0){
                //logged in stuff here
                $logged=1;
                
               }else{
                   header('Location:logout.php');
                   exit();
               }
               
               }elseif(isset($_COOKIE['id_cookie'])){
                $session_id=$_COOKIE['id_cookie'];
                $session_pass=$_COOKIE['pass_cookie'];
                
                //checking the member data
               $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE    
    id='$session_id' AND password='$session_pass' LIMIT 1")or die("Could not check member");
               $count_count=mysql_num_rows($query);
               if(count_count>0){
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                            

    $session_username=$row['username'];
                    }
                   //create sessions
                   $_SESSION['username']=$session_username;
                   $_SESSION['id']=$session_id;
                   $_SESSION['pass']=$session_pass;
                   
                //logged in stuff here
                    $logged=1;
                
               }else{
                   header('Location:logout.php');
                   exit();
                   }
               }

    ?>
```

Comment: store `logged` in like `$_SESSION['logged']=1;` - then you will be able to access it from everywhere (providing you are checking session on other pages) - also learn about error reporting in php - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Comment: What happens when you use `include` instead of `include_once`?

Comment: actually. nothing changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$logged is set inside a conditional, so trace back through to understand how you might not hit a random redirect (reminds me of the crazy "goto" days which I through we progressed past) and end up with $logged not being set.  Or initialize $logged at the beginning of the included script.

Comment: So by setting $logged=0; at the beginning of global.php will solve the issue?  It seems to have worked.  Thank you.